# javascript: actions being run on elements for which the if's condition was not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following if-test

```
$("div#groupA > ul").each(function(){
    if (!($("div#groupA > ul").css("display")==="none")) {
        $('div#groupA > ul > input[value="9999"]').remove();
    }
});
$("div#groupA").fadeIn();
```

OR

```
$("div#groupA > ul").each(function(){
    if ( $("div#groupA > ul").css("display")!=="none" ) {
        $('div#groupA > ul > input[value="9999"]').remove();
    }
});
$("div#groupA").fadeIn();
```

But both are removing `<input value="9999">`s that are in other divs outside of `<div id="groupA">`.

How do I get it to remove only `<input value="9999">`s that are inside `<div id="groupA">`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something unusual with the switch statement that encased this.

```
switch(true){
    case (q1===0):
        // do some stuff
        // purposefully no break
    case (this.value==="bar"):
        $("div#groupA > ul").each(function(){
            if ( $("div#groupA > ul").css("display")!=="none" ) {
            $('div#groupA > ul > input[value="9999"]').remove();
            }
        });
        $("div#groupA").fadeIn();
        break;
    case (this.value==="foobar"):
        // do some other stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do some more other stuff
        break;
}
```

The swtich(true) was working fine, except when I did an evaluation inside of a case. Then it crapped itself (and only did bits and pieces of the if-statement).

What I ended up doing was:

```
if(q1===0){
    // do some stuff
}
switch(this.value){
    case ("bar"):
        $("div#groupA > ul").each(function(){
            if ( $("div#groupA > ul").css("display")!=="none" ) {
            $('div#groupA > ul > input[value="9999"]').remove();
            }
        });
        $("div#groupA").fadeIn();
        break;
    case ("foobar"):
        // do some other stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do some more other stuff
        break;
}
```

btw, sorry for not posting back right away: it never e-mailed me when there was a new response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#groupA').find('ul').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('input[value="9999"]').remove();
    }
});
```

Ease up on the super-specific selectors. They make sense for CSS but they make excessive use of sizzle and aren't as optimal as using JQuery's native traversal functions.

`div#groupA > ul > input[value="9999"]` makes no sense. The `>` symbol means the following is a direct child of the parent. Odds are your `input` is inside something else, like an `li`.

Comment: Post your HTML man. If this code doesn't work, it's your DOM that's the problem.

Comment: I tried .is(':visible') in every which way, and it just would not work, so I had to stick with the .css("display")!=="none")